# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{[1^2x]+[2^2x]+[3^2x]+...[n^2x]}{n^3}$, where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function $x\in R$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, summation

> Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{[1^2x]+[2^2x]+[3^2x]+...[n^2x]}{n^3}$, where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function $x\in R$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{[1^2x]+[2^2x]+[3^2x]+...[n^2x]}{n^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum_{r=1}^n[r^2x]}{n^3}$

Without $[.]$, I could have written $\sum r^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$. Not sure how to approach now.

If we try to convert it into integration, we have $\dfrac1n$ which could be written as $dx$, we need $\dfrac rn$ to be written as varibale (maybe $y$ here, since $x$ is already given), but we have $r^2$ in $[.]$, I don't think we can take $n^2$ inside.

Can the squeeze theorem be applicable here? But now sure how.

Comment: Remove each floor using $a\leq [a]<a+1$. Your sum gets bounded between $x\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2}{n^3}$ and $x\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2}{n^3}+\frac{n}{n^3}$.

Comment: What do you get if you use $r^2 x \le \left[ {r^2 x} \right] \le r^2 x + 1$ and estimate your sum from below and above?

Comment: Thanks, will attempt now.

Comment: so, the answer is $\frac x3$? Is that correct?

Comment: @aarbee Yes, that is correct.

Comment: For the floor, $a\leq [a]<a+1$ is wrong.  It should be $a-1 < [a] \leq a$.  But the calculations here end up the same.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you. I was getting confused after seeing the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$S_n=[1^2x]+[2^2x]+[3^2x]+...[n^2x],$$
where $[x]$ is GIF.
Use $$k^2x-1<[k^2 x]\le k^2 x$$, then we can sqeez
$$x\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2-nx < S_n \le x\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2.$$
We get the squeez law as
$$\implies \lim_{m\to\infty} x\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)/6-n}{n^3} < \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n^3} \le \lim_{n \to \infty} x\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)/6}{n^3}.$$
$$\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n^3}=\frac{x}{3}$$